# how to extract date from datetime column in google sheet using query funtion(SQL)

Tags: sql, date, google-sheets, timestamp, data-analysis

Column value is shown in the figure and I am trying to extract the date from the datetime column.

[image]

I m trying to use the following command

```
=QUERY(A:B, "Select A where B is not NULL '"&SPLIT(A2:A," ")&"'",1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(DATEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,"(.+) "))))
```

[image: Datevalue google sheets regexextract date from date and time]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(1*SPLIT(A1:A10; " ");;1)
```

and set formatting to Date

Answer (score 0):

To do this with `query()`, use the `toDate()` [scalar function](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#scalar-functions):

`=query(A1:A, "select toDate(A) label toDate(A) '' ", 0)`